# Web2py: How to create playlists structure on database and display them

Tags: web2py

I'm working on a web2py application that lets an user add and delete tracks from a playlist, and then add and delete playlists from a list of playlists.

My tables look like this:

```
db.define_table('track',
            Field('artist'),
            Field('album'),
            Field('title'),
            Field('duration', 'float'),
            Field('rating', 'float'),
            Field('num_plays', 'integer'),
            Field('created_by', default=get_user_email()),
            Field('created_on', default=datetime.datetime.utcnow()),
            Field('track_source',default='manual'),
            Field('track_uri')
            )

db.define_table('playlist',
            ......
            )
```

How do I define my playlist table as to include a title and all the tracks that are linked to that playlist?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. The most flexible is to create a third table to link tracks and playlists in a [many-to-many relationship](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Many-to-many):

```
db.define_table('playlist_tracks',
    Field('playlist', 'reference playlist'),
    Field('track', 'reference track'))
```

The above approach allows the most flexibility in terms of queries, as you can for example, easily query to which or to how many playlists a given track belongs.

A simpler approach is to add a [`list:reference`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#list--type--and-contains) field to the playlist table:

```
db.define_table('playlist',
    Field('tracks', 'list:reference'), ...)
```

The `list:reference` approach is fine if your queries are limited to retrieving a single or small number of playlists and their associated tracks, but more complex queries related to tracks or large numbers of playlists and tracks can become inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your response! How would my api code look to add tracks to the second option you gave me?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what your API code looks like now, but in general, `list:reference` fields take a list of record IDs: `db.playlist.insert(..., tracks=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, where 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are values of the `id` field from the `db.track` table.

Comment: My API code is as follows:

db.define_table('track',
.....
)

db.define_table('playlist',
                ......
                )

db.define_table('playlist_reference',
                Field('playlist', 'reference playlist'),
                Field('track','reference track')
                )

How would I be able for example, to retrieve all the tracks within a playlist of title x?

Comment: See the many-to-many link above. If you still need help, update the question, or better yet, ask a new one.